# How can you reset values that are set static by a decorator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have the following decorator and method for displaying transfer status:

```
def static_vars(**kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
        return func
    return decorate

@static_vars(counter=0)
def TransferStats(transferedBytes, totalBytes):
    if (transferedBytes / totalBytes) >= TransferStats.counter:
        log.info('Transferred: {}% [{}/{}]'.format(round((transferedBytes/totalBytes)*100,2), transferedBytes, totalBytes))
        TransferStats.counter += 0.025
```

My problem comes when I want to transfer multiple items, `counter` is never reset to `0`. Is there a way for me to reset `counter`? Is there a better way to do this altogether?

*Clarification Edit*: `TransferStats` is referenced as a callback method, so the parameters (I think) have to remain as `(int,int)` - hence the decorator.

Comment: It sounds like `TransferStats` should be a method of a class here, with the counter as an instance attribute.

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be to do `TransferStats.counter = 0` from anywhere you can reference `TransferStats`. Using global variables (even when they're "hidden" as attributes on a function) is fragile design. @user2357112's suggestion of using a method with the data in an instance variable is a better design, since you can have multiple independent counters that way.